# "Startup" pipe for Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I would like to have two pipes attached to HttpClient request that will execute some function on the beggining of request and when the request finished. So far I've found "finalize" operator to execute function on request finished, but I couldn't find equivalent for request starting.

My code so far:

```
this.http.get<MyModel>('api/model')
    .pipe(
      // TODO missing something for startup
      finalize(() => console.log('on start'))
    )
    .subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

How to achieve this result? Is there any built-in operator in RxJS or should I write my own? Or maybe any alternatives?

Comment: I think you can just place the code you want before calling `this.http.get`...

Comment: I know it would be the simpliest solution. But i would like it to be really nice, you know. :)

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve ? There could be a better solution than this.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: I've found a better, less known solution.
There is a [defer](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/defer) Observable creation function, not a operator.

It can be used like this:

```
defer(() => {
    console.log('on start');
    return this.http.get<MyModel>('api/model').pipe(
        finalize(() => console.log('on finish'))
    )
}).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Best thing is that it captures HttpClient in a closure and you can pass this Observable around without subscribing to it.

---

[startWith](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/startWith) is the closest operator you can get. It needs to match type of http result though.

Comment: The idea with defer is great, but I think startWith is the way to go. I have posted an answer based on this.

Answer (score -1):

Based on @Tomasz Błachut proposal with startWith operator. It requires some hacks but works as expected.

The idea is to use startWith operator with immiedately invoked function that will do what I want and return null. Than we add skip(1) to avoid this null in subscription.

It works as expected. Final code:

```
this.http.get<MyModel>('api/model')
    .pipe(
      startWith((() => {
        console.log('on start');
        return null;
      })()),
      skip(1),
      finalize(() => console.log('on end'))
    )
    .subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: Glad I helped. I wonder will it compile in TS strict mode? null isn't a subtype of MyModel there. Yet again you could wrap this in own startup operator and do some explicit casts in it.

Comment: I've checked - it won't.

Comment: startWith doesn't handle functions and never call it.. don't know how it could have worked for you